# Flask pyodbc showing "Login failed for user" when using "TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes"

Tags: sql-server, flask, pyodbc, pypyodbc, trustedconnection

I have the following connection: `cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=nameofmyserver;DATABASE=nameofmydb;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes;")`

The Flask app is on IIS and has Windows Authentication enabled.

On one route, I return `request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER').split('\\')[1]` which returns my username as expected

When I try and connect to MSSQL I get an error as follows:

`[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\7A6AUSRV02$'.`

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

I have tried changing the driver to no avail

What I am trying to do is list stored procedures that the current logged in user has access to

Comment: Windows authentication uses the account that executes an application to connect to the database, not any environment variables. It seems you tried to connect to a remote database using a *local* account. In that case the connection is made using the client machine's computer name, in this case `7A6AUSRV02$`

Comment: `is on IIS` make sure the application runs under a domain account with permissions to connect to the database, not a local or app pool account.

Comment: If we had dozens of domain users accessing this application, how would I go about that? Have updated the question with more detail. Each user must connect to the DB with their own account.

Comment: The account making the connection is the web app's account, not the browser user. There's only one account involved.

Comment: So I am unable to connect to MS SQL as myself and likewise, others are unable to log into MS SQL as themselves?

Comment: `Each user must connect to the DB with their own account` that's a different problem, and not necessarily a good idea from a security perspective. You'd need to *impersonate* the end user and connect to the database using that user's account. That's done in the application code, it's not something that can be enabled for an entire session. It's dangerous because *anything* done by the application while impersonation is active will use the end user's permissions

Comment: Have you any references on what I would need to read/do please?

Comment: [Impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/xh507fc5(v=vs.100)) is available in all .NET runtimes and even the ancient classic ASP. That's generally frowned upon for decades though, because if an admin logs into a hacked site, malicious code will be able to run using the admin's permissions

Comment: `what I would need to read/do` what *do* you want to do? Why should a web app connect using end user credentials at all?

Comment: I want users to be able to go into a web application and have stored procedures listed that they have access to in MS SQL and run them. They can not currently log into SSMS so they need a web app. This is currently done via an Excel file.

Comment: It seems the problems are caused by the attempted solution to whatever the problem is. There's seldom any good reason to have user-specific stored procedures. End users never use SSMS. If you want to generate reports, analytics etc you can use a reporting engine. The stuff that needs per-user permissions is the reports, not the database.

Comment: `They can not currently log into SSMS so they need a web app` not really??? Excel can read data from a database using eg Power Query/Power Pivot and ingest millions of rows, as much as the client machine can handle, in a compressed columnstore format. That connection will be made using the end user's account. The internal engine is the same as SSAS/Power BI which allows publishing PowerPivot models to Power BI (with a few tweaks)

Comment: So the situation is we have dozens of stored procedures. It's a one to many relationship so one user could have access to several SPs. Another user could have same access. A third could have entirely different. 

They need a web app as Excel is being phased out.

Comment: That's what you assume the solution will look like. It's not something used by either web apps or reporting engines. What are you actually trying to do? What are the users trying to read? Why not use a reporting engine? SQL Server's built-in Reporting Services probably do what you want already

Comment: There are several dozen stored procedures. There are a few dozen users. Each user has access to one or many stored procedures. They currently select a SP in Excel, fill in params and it executes the SP and delivers results.

Answer (score 0):

This

DOMAIN\7A6AUSRV02$

Is the computer account for the server named 7A6AUSRV02.  It's a domain account, and can be granted access to SQL Server like any other Windows domain account.  eg

```
create login [DOMAIN\7A6AUSRV02$] from windows
create user [DOMAIN\7A6AUSRV02$] for login [DOMAIN\7A6AUSRV02$]
```

You should have a database role that defines the database permissions needed for the flask app, and you should add this user to that role, eg

```
  alter role MyFlaskApp add member [DOMAIN\7A6AUSRV02$]
```

Comment: I want to connect using *MY* username which is something entirely different

Comment: Why do you want that? It matters. There are better ways than trying to impersonate the browser user

Comment: I don't know if Flask can do Windows impersonation.  ASP and ASP.NET can.  You could grant that account rights to impersonate the users in SQL Server with `EXECUTE AS LOGIN=[Domain\RemoteUser]`

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, why should an IIS app run as `SYSTEM` in the first place? Why not use a proper gMSA for it?

Comment: That's not SYSTEM it's the computer account, which low-privilege service accounts like Network Service and per-service SIDs use for communicating on the network.  The only thing wrong with using the computer account is if you've got a bunch of different services running on the server, then it can accumulate permissions.